# Remove the underscore that appears when I hover over an image linked to a website

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following snippet of code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  # some code
  shinyjs::hidden(div(
    navbarPage(title = div(
      a(href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", target = "_blank", img(src="img_1.png", filetype="image/png", height="30px", width="90px", style="position: relative; margin: -15px 5px; display: right-align;")),
      a(href="https://fr.quora.com/", target = "_blank", img(src="img_2.png", filetype="image/png", height="30px", width="60px", style="position: relative; margin: -15px 15px; display: right-align;")),
      "Indicators"
      ),
      # some code
    )
  ))
))
```

When I hover over `img_1.png`, an underscore appears to the right of `img_1.png` itself. The same thing happens with `img_2.png`. How do I remove the underscore that appears to the right of the images? Is there a general solution? I know there is something like `text-decoration: none;` in CSS, but how does it integrate with Shiny? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the display property of the anchor tag from the default `inline` to `inline-block`.

```
a(href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", 
  style = "display:inline-block", 
  img(src="img_2.png"))
```